# How to connect many short eulerian cycles into only a few longer ones?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to connect eulerian cycles into longer ones without exceed a value.

So, I have this eulerian cycles and their length in a list. The maximal length of a cycle can be for example 500. The length of all cycles added up is 6176.778566350282. By connecting them cleverly together there could be probably only 13 or 14 cycles. But I don't really know how I could do that. I tried to just add one cycle to another but there I got 21 cycles out. The problem is that if you have a cycle of these numbers for example: [8, 21, 9, 22, 8, 23, 9, 24, 8] and you want to integrate this cycle [10, 11, 12, 10] it will not work because in the first cycle there is no edge of the number 10. I just started then a new cycle with this numbers [10, 11, 12, 10] and saved [8, 21, 9, 22, 8, 23, 9, 24, 8] as one of the 21 result cycles. But with this method I don't really get a good result. What would be a cleverer way to solve this problem?

This is an example how the list of the short eulerian cycles looks like:

```
[([0, 1, 2, 0], 36.36630772776802), ([0, 3, 1, 4, 0], 93.83277865587606), ([0, 5, 1, 6, 0], 45.79353710664728), ([0, 7, 1, 8, 0], 49.60782827778143), ([0, 9, 1, 10, 0], 73.2674533926481), ([0, 11, 1, 12, 0], 75.52124688926921), ([0, 13, 1, 14, 0], 57.88021234723078), ([0, 15, 1, 16, 0], 62.21469065955568), ([0, 17, 1, 18, 0], 81.43809748917617), ([0, 19, 1, 20, 0], 98.88867905572438), ([0, 21, 1, 22, 0], 95.3596513800762), ([0, 23, 1, 24, 0], 116.15359042770964), ([2, 3, 4, 2], 49.106297391220245), ([2, 5, 3, 6, 2], 71.5422470782724), ([2, 7, 3, 8, 2], 50.237654764168), ([2, 9, 3, 10, 2], 71.36355688043689), ([2, 11, 3, 12, 2], 44.474596239420634), ([2, 13, 3, 14, 2], 103.42527218232905), ([2, 15, 3, 16, 2], 65.92444557445982), ([2, 17, 3, 18, 2], 83.30561323888043), ([2, 19, 3, 20, 2], 144.20150278029047), ([2, 21, 3, 22, 2], 131.70030082856), ([2, 23, 3, 24, 2], 141.63032737825358), ([4, 5, 6, 4], 42.10300780814433), ([4, 7, 5, 8, 4], 88.13162862262575), ([4, 9, 5, 10, 4], 29.40312423743285), ([4, 
11, 5, 12, 4], 35.06685249446684), ([4, 13, 5, 14, 4], 83.54113932583394), ([4, 15, 5, 16, 4], 57.669814210895076), ([4, 17, 5, 18, 4], 85.16088821443248), ([4, 19, 5, 20, 4], 115.83839679838714), ([4, 21, 5, 22, 4], 96.32509817470469), ([4, 23, 5, 24, 4], 95.72504474795447), ([6, 7, 8, 6], 39.680511478789455), ([6, 9, 7, 10, 6], 78.55998969220359), ([6, 11, 7, 12, 6], 75.38181527864062), ([6, 13, 7, 14, 6], 65.59514045044449), ([6, 15, 7, 16, 6], 64.00893982862813), ([6, 17, 7, 18, 6], 82.99423226082924), ([6, 19, 7, 20, 6], 107.80803412093549), ([6, 21, 7, 22, 6], 104.34384551877056), ([6, 23, 7, 24, 6], 125.5684717784), ([8, 9, 10, 8], 52.130784276071026), ([8, 11, 9, 12, 8], 60.084249983353345), ([8, 13, 9, 14, 
8], 80.8264707041123), ([8, 15, 9, 16, 8], 56.067658306081576), ([8, 17, 9, 18, 8], 87.79739969269264), ([8, 19, 9, 20, 8], 115.04095207094785), 
([8, 21, 9, 22, 8], 100.28892183336735), ([8, 23, 9, 24, 8], 107.98171312085222), ([10, 11, 12, 10], 18.073592581964586), ([10, 13, 11, 14, 10], 
86.59048377734861), ([10, 15, 11, 16, 10], 53.62896051047471), ([10, 17, 11, 18, 10], 79.42707393175432), ([10, 19, 11, 20, 10], 121.75438335508098), ([10, 21, 11, 22, 10], 103.13320830479722), ([10, 23, 11, 24, 10], 104.67092453129686), ([12, 13, 14, 12], 65.01056040398879), ([12, 15, 13, 16, 12], 73.92038351218434), ([12, 17, 13, 18, 12], 75.85986620162797), ([12, 19, 13, 20, 12], 99.9668143111241), ([12, 21, 13, 22, 12], 97.01425784207544), ([12, 23, 13, 24, 12], 113.28618776429398), ([14, 15, 16, 14], 53.12806382231952), ([14, 17, 15, 18, 14], 83.32318283097464), ([14, 
19, 15, 20, 14], 59.489711796339975), ([14, 21, 15, 22, 14], 49.93204117686305), ([14, 23, 15, 24, 14], 59.39628730132421), ([16, 17, 18, 16], 76.30230372794964), ([16, 19, 17, 20, 16], 151.38369644764225), ([16, 21, 17, 22, 16], 137.27131752575687), ([16, 23, 17, 24, 16], 146.11467181532439), ([18, 19, 20, 18], 28.731124011957917), ([18, 21, 19, 22, 18], 51.78367537918862), ([18, 23, 19, 24, 18], 86.45013419422762), ([20, 21, 22, 
20], 39.010097887844154), ([20, 23, 21, 24, 20], 63.48159687540681), ([22, 23, 24, 22], 22.283951753399037)]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How many result cycles should [[2, 0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 2]] lead to?

Comment: Dependent from the length of each cycle and how long a result cycle can be. If each cycle is 15 long and the result cycle can be maximal 20 long it should lead to two result cycles, if the result cycle can be 40 long in one.

Comment: Assume that the sum of the values for those two cycles is under the limit.

Comment: Then there should be one result cycle that could look like this:  [2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2]

Comment: Great! I have a complicated idea that will take some time to write up. Is the example above typical of what you want to run?

Comment: Also, we can't split Euler cycles, can we? So if we had [2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2] in the input, that's not equivalent to having [2, 0, 1, 2] and [2, 3, 4, 2] separately?

Comment: There is no problem with splitting it up if the original length is also obtained. So if you merge```([0, 1, 2, 0], 36.36630772776802), ([0, 3, 1, 4, 0], 93.83277865587606)]``` into [0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 1, 2, 0] and then you want to split it up again you should know how long [0, 1, 2, 0] and [0, 3, 1, 4, 0] originally was. Otherwise, it will be probably impossible to be sure if the merged cycle is not too long.

Comment: It can be also shorter another example of the input can be:
```[([0, 1, 4, 0], 31.296328855798894), ([0, 2, 3, 0], 23.81145881047212), ([0, 5, 1, 6, 0], 35.83230475833858), ([2, 4, 5, 2], 36.43251060335925), 
([3, 5, 6, 3], 21.27512202507249)]```

Comment: How do we know what the value of each of the pieces is though?

Comment: I meant that theoretically it is no problem to split it up. Practically it will be not easy to find out how long it originally was.

Comment: I would expect a random approach to wind up with most cycles at anywhere between half to full size.  So if optimal is 14 and you wound up with 21, that's not actually unreasonable.

Comment: If I use my program with the input that is in the comments I get such an result:```[([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 3, 0, 1, 4, 0], 76.38290969134351), ([0, 5, 1, 6, 0], 35.83230475833858), ([2, 4, 5, 2], 36.43251060335925)]``` when the maximal length can be 80. So here I get from 5 input cycles 3 output cycles. That is then not that good anymore.

Comment: Although I'm just trying to find a better way by hand and I haven't really found one for this example. But by the longer example there will be some better solutions. This are the last cycles from my result cycle list. They are short therefor that they can be 500 long: ([18, 23, 19, 24, 18], 86.45013419422762), ([20, 23, 21, 24, 20], 63.48159687540681), ([22, 23, 24, 22], 22.283951753399037) this must go better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I designed an elaborate branch-and-price scheme and then realized that it probably wouldn’t work well. Here’s a much simpler local search that achieves 14 cycles on your sample input.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
import random

# pip3 install networkx if necessary.
import networkx as nx


# The input consists of the variables maximum_length and cycles.

maximum_length = 500
cycles = [
    ([0, 1, 2, 0], 36.36630772776802),
    ([0, 3, 1, 4, 0], 93.83277865587606),
    ([0, 5, 1, 6, 0], 45.79353710664728),
    ([0, 7, 1, 8, 0], 49.60782827778143),
    ([0, 9, 1, 10, 0], 73.2674533926481),
    ([0, 11, 1, 12, 0], 75.52124688926921),
    ([0, 13, 1, 14, 0], 57.88021234723078),
    ([0, 15, 1, 16, 0], 62.21469065955568),
    ([0, 17, 1, 18, 0], 81.43809748917617),
    ([0, 19, 1, 20, 0], 98.88867905572438),
    ([0, 21, 1, 22, 0], 95.3596513800762),
    ([0, 23, 1, 24, 0], 116.15359042770964),
    ([2, 3, 4, 2], 49.106297391220245),
    ([2, 5, 3, 6, 2], 71.5422470782724),
    ([2, 7, 3, 8, 2], 50.237654764168),
    ([2, 9, 3, 10, 2], 71.36355688043689),
    ([2, 11, 3, 12, 2], 44.474596239420634),
    ([2, 13, 3, 14, 2], 103.42527218232905),
    ([2, 15, 3, 16, 2], 65.92444557445982),
    ([2, 17, 3, 18, 2], 83.30561323888043),
    ([2, 19, 3, 20, 2], 144.20150278029047),
    ([2, 21, 3, 22, 2], 131.70030082856),
    ([2, 23, 3, 24, 2], 141.63032737825358),
    ([4, 5, 6, 4], 42.10300780814433),
    ([4, 7, 5, 8, 4], 88.13162862262575),
    ([4, 9, 5, 10, 4], 29.40312423743285),
    ([4, 11, 5, 12, 4], 35.06685249446684),
    ([4, 13, 5, 14, 4], 83.54113932583394),
    ([4, 15, 5, 16, 4], 57.669814210895076),
    ([4, 17, 5, 18, 4], 85.16088821443248),
    ([4, 19, 5, 20, 4], 115.83839679838714),
    ([4, 21, 5, 22, 4], 96.32509817470469),
    ([4, 23, 5, 24, 4], 95.72504474795447),
    ([6, 7, 8, 6], 39.680511478789455),
    ([6, 9, 7, 10, 6], 78.55998969220359),
    ([6, 11, 7, 12, 6], 75.38181527864062),
    ([6, 13, 7, 14, 6], 65.59514045044449),
    ([6, 15, 7, 16, 6], 64.00893982862813),
    ([6, 17, 7, 18, 6], 82.99423226082924),
    ([6, 19, 7, 20, 6], 107.80803412093549),
    ([6, 21, 7, 22, 6], 104.34384551877056),
    ([6, 23, 7, 24, 6], 125.5684717784),
    ([8, 9, 10, 8], 52.130784276071026),
    ([8, 11, 9, 12, 8], 60.084249983353345),
    ([8, 13, 9, 14, 8], 80.8264707041123),
    ([8, 15, 9, 16, 8], 56.067658306081576),
    ([8, 17, 9, 18, 8], 87.79739969269264),
    ([8, 19, 9, 20, 8], 115.04095207094785),
    ([8, 21, 9, 22, 8], 100.28892183336735),
    ([8, 23, 9, 24, 8], 107.98171312085222),
    ([10, 11, 12, 10], 18.073592581964586),
    ([10, 13, 11, 14, 10], 86.59048377734861),
    ([10, 15, 11, 16, 10], 53.62896051047471),
    ([10, 17, 11, 18, 10], 79.42707393175432),
    ([10, 19, 11, 20, 10], 121.75438335508098),
    ([10, 21, 11, 22, 10], 103.13320830479722),
    ([10, 23, 11, 24, 10], 104.67092453129686),
    ([12, 13, 14, 12], 65.01056040398879),
    ([12, 15, 13, 16, 12], 73.92038351218434),
    ([12, 17, 13, 18, 12], 75.85986620162797),
    ([12, 19, 13, 20, 12], 99.9668143111241),
    ([12, 21, 13, 22, 12], 97.01425784207544),
    ([12, 23, 13, 24, 12], 113.28618776429398),
    ([14, 15, 16, 14], 53.12806382231952),
    ([14, 17, 15, 18, 14], 83.32318283097464),
    ([14, 19, 15, 20, 14], 59.489711796339975),
    ([14, 21, 15, 22, 14], 49.93204117686305),
    ([14, 23, 15, 24, 14], 59.39628730132421),
    ([16, 17, 18, 16], 76.30230372794964),
    ([16, 19, 17, 20, 16], 151.38369644764225),
    ([16, 21, 17, 22, 16], 137.27131752575687),
    ([16, 23, 17, 24, 16], 146.11467181532439),
    ([18, 19, 20, 18], 28.731124011957917),
    ([18, 21, 19, 22, 18], 51.78367537918862),
    ([18, 23, 19, 24, 18], 86.45013419422762),
    ([20, 21, 22, 20], 39.010097887844154),
    ([20, 23, 21, 24, 20], 63.48159687540681),
    ([22, 23, 24, 22], 22.283951753399037),
]
for cycle, length in cycles:
    assert cycle[0] == cycle[-1]
    assert 0 <= length <= maximum_length


# Two cycles can be merged if and only if there exists a vertex that they have
# in common. Compute the graph where each cycle is a node and each pair of
# cycles that can be merged is an edge. A set of cycles can be merged if and
# only if the total length does not exceed the maximum and the corresponding set
# of nodes induces a connected subgraph.

inverted_index = defaultdict(list)
for i, (cycle, length) in enumerate(cycles):
    for v in set(cycle):
        inverted_index[v].append(i)
cycle_graph = nx.Graph()
for i, (cycle, length) in enumerate(cycles):
    cycle_graph.add_node(i, length=length)
for posting_list in inverted_index.values():
    for e in combinations(posting_list, 2):
        cycle_graph.add_edge(*e)
lengths = [round(length * 2**40) / 2**40 for (cycle, length) in cycles]


# We want to find the smallest partition of cycles into mergeable parts. This
# code implements a greedy local search. Initialize the partition where every
# cycle is in its own part. For some number of steps, move one cycle to another
# part, respecting the connectivity constraint.


def make_part_graph(part):
    part_graph = cycle_graph.subgraph(part)
    return nx.Graph(
        part_graph,
        can_move=set(part_graph.nodes()) - set(nx.articulation_points(part_graph)),
        length=sum(lengths[i] for i in part_graph.nodes()),
    )


def merge_cycles(indexes):
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in indexes:
        cycle, length = cycles[i]
        for j in range(1, len(cycle)):
            g.add_edge(cycle[j - 1], cycle[j])
    cycle = []
    for u, v in nx.eulerian_circuit(g):
        if not cycle:
            cycle.append(u)
        cycle.append(v)
    return cycle, sum(lengths[i] for i in indexes)


labels = list(range(len(cycles)))
cycle_subgraphs = {i: make_part_graph({i}) for i in range(len(cycles))}
for step in range(10000):
    moves = []
    for tail, cycle_subgraph in cycle_subgraphs.items():
        for i in cycle_subgraph.graph["can_move"]:
            for j in cycle_graph.neighbors(i):
                head = labels[j]
                if (
                    head != tail
                    and cycle_subgraphs[head].graph["length"] + lengths[i]
                    <= maximum_length
                ):
                    moves.append((i, tail, head))
    i, tail, head = random.choice(moves)
    labels[i] = head
    cycle_subgraphs[tail] = make_part_graph(set(cycle_subgraphs[tail].nodes()) - {i})
    cycle_subgraphs[head] = make_part_graph(set(cycle_subgraphs[head].nodes()) | {i})
for cycle_subgraph in cycle_subgraphs.values():
    part = sorted(cycle_subgraph.nodes())
    if not part:
        continue
    print(*merge_cycles(part))
```

Output:

```
[0, 23, 11, 24, 8, 23, 9, 3, 10, 2, 9, 24, 10, 23, 1, 24, 0, 21, 1, 22, 0] 495.5294363403709
[0, 19, 17, 20, 16, 19, 22, 18, 21, 3, 22, 2, 21, 19, 1, 20, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0] 479.5498888177626
[6, 23, 17, 24, 16, 10, 15, 11, 14, 10, 13, 11, 16, 23, 7, 24, 6] 411.90258788154733
[0, 9, 22, 8, 21, 9, 18, 16, 17, 18, 8, 17, 9, 16, 8, 15, 9, 12, 8, 6, 7, 8, 11, 9, 1, 10, 0] 493.488498414883
[2, 5, 3, 6, 19, 9, 10, 8, 9, 20, 23, 21, 24, 20, 8, 19, 7, 20, 6, 2] 410.00361442163285
[0, 7, 22, 6, 21, 7, 16, 12, 15, 20, 14, 19, 11, 20, 10, 19, 15, 13, 16, 6, 15, 7, 1, 8, 0] 473.1250922887857
[0, 13, 1, 14, 0, 11, 22, 10, 21, 11, 5, 12, 4, 11, 3, 12, 2, 11, 1, 12, 0, 1, 2, 0] 352.442424002953
[0, 3, 1, 4, 23, 15, 24, 14, 23, 5, 24, 4, 7, 5, 8, 4, 0] 337.0857393277802
[4, 21, 13, 7, 14, 8, 13, 9, 14, 6, 13, 22, 23, 24, 22, 20, 21, 22, 12, 21, 5, 22, 4, 9, 5, 10, 4] 430.458141050015
[2, 23, 3, 24, 2, 13, 3, 14, 2, 7, 12, 6, 11, 7, 10, 6, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7, 3, 8, 2] 491.33806710373847
[0, 15, 22, 14, 21, 15, 5, 20, 12, 10, 11, 12, 19, 13, 20, 4, 19, 5, 16, 4, 15, 1, 16, 0] 403.69534973878945
[0, 17, 22, 16, 21, 17, 11, 18, 19, 3, 20, 2, 19, 20, 18, 10, 17, 1, 18, 0] 471.0691157389365
[2, 15, 16, 14, 4, 13, 24, 18, 23, 19, 24, 12, 23, 13, 5, 14, 15, 3, 16, 2, 3, 4, 2] 451.43626807235523
[2, 17, 15, 18, 14, 12, 13, 14, 17, 13, 18, 12, 17, 7, 18, 6, 17, 5, 18, 4, 17, 3, 18, 2] 475.65434315073435
```